# assign value to variable in getQueryStringParams

Tags: javascript

Below code gives me what I want but it gives undefined when stored in var- I would like the value assigned to a variable in getQueryStringParams. How to achieve this?

```
const url = location.href;

function getQueryStringParams(params, url) {
  // first decode URL to get readable data
  const href = decodeURIComponent(url || window.location.href);
  // regular expression to get value
  const regEx = new RegExp('[?&]' + params + '=([^&#]*)', 'i');
  const value = regEx.exec(href);
  // return the value if exist
  return value ? value[1] : null;
};

getQueryStringParams('region', url);
```

Comment: Can you add one sample url as input ?

Comment: SitePages/category.aspx?region=amea

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily using the `URLSearchParams` object like this

```
function getQueryStringParams(params) {
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

  return searchParams.get(params);
};

getQueryStringParams('region');
```

Comment: ,I get the same output using above code but I want to assign this output to variable. that's where i get undefined

Comment: function getQueryStringParams(params) {
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

  return searchParams.get(params);
};

var region=getQueryStringParams('region');//I get undefined here

Comment: It only works if you have an entity like `?region=whatever` in your href.

Comment: I have this- SitePages/category.aspx?region=amea but when I add var, it goes undefined

Comment: What is displayed when you enter `window.location.search` in your console?